# FB APP - get permissions - check login status ONCE

Tags: sdk, facebook

I'm building FB app, need to check Does user like my page or not.
To arrange it, I need to get permissions from user.
I arranged Login (So that while entering in application it requires login),
but after login I need to redirect to the same page, App-s index..
After first login, it doesn't stop.

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => '139844459464342',
'secret' => '*********************',
 ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
try {
  // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
 $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log($e);
 $user = null;
}
}


  if ($me) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'canvas' => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 1,
            'display' => 'page',
            'req_perms' => 'user_likes',
            'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/my-aki-tim/',
            'cancel_url'=> 'http://apps.facebook.com/my-aki-tim/'
));
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

it works, but I can not stop Logged in user..
Please help me if you can, thanks in advance

Comment: I removed your secret key from your code above.  Please keep in mind that key should not be published.  I would suggest generating a new key immediately via the reset link at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/139844459464342/summary

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not stop Logged in user"? Is you app constantly redirecting or you have anything else in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable `$me` which is not defined in your code and this causing redirection loop. Either change `$me` to `$user_profile` or rewrite an assignment:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
```